# javascript global variables can't store values if it implies extracting them from HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, variables

Ok, so I've got this function which enables the user to move a fly left, right, up and down with the keyboard's arrow keys. The piece of code presented below works (I only use Internet Explorer to test my scripts):

```
<html>

<head>

<script language="javascript" text="text/javascript">

    var coordenadax=300;
    var coordenaday=250;

function coordenadas(){

    var key=window.event.keyCode;
    switch (key) {
        case 37: coordenadax=coordenadax-10; break;
        case 38: coordenaday=coordenaday-10; break;
        case 39: coordenadax=coordenadax+10; break;
        case 40: coordenaday=coordenaday+10; break;
}

mosca.style.left=coordenadax;
mosca.style.top=coordenaday;

}

</script>

</head>

<body onkeyDown="coordenadas()">

<div id="mosca" style="width:48px; height:34px; top:250px; left:300px; position:relative; 
 z-index:1;">
    <img src="fly.png">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

However, if I change:

```
<script language="javascript" text="text/javascript">

    var coordenadax=300;
    var coordenaday=250;

function coordenadas(){
```

to:

```
<script language="javascript" text="text/javascript">

    var coordenadax=mosca.style.left;
    var coordenaday=mosca.style.top;

function coordenadas(){
```

or even to:

```
<script language="javascript" text="text/javascript">

    var coordenadax=document.getElementById('mosca').style.left;
    var coordenaday=document.getElementById('mosca').style.top;

function coordenadas(){
```

in order to retrieve those values from the div element, rather than just giving them to the global variables, then the fly won't move at all and I just can't see why...

Comment: when perisiting such you need to stop one dot sooner and grab .left each time from a memozied style object; ex: var coordenaday=document.getElementById('mosca').style; ... coordenaday.top;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a javascript script, it's executed "in place" (The browser creates objects and executes codes in the order they are defined). When the browser executes:

```
var coordenadax=document.getElementById('mosca').style.left;
var coordenaday=document.getElementById('mosca').style.top;
```

The object with id "mosca" has not been created yet (You create the object after the script), and it drops an error. (Check the developer's console, probably it's in there).

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is executing as the page loads. Because the JS code comes before the actual markup, the script is being executed before the `#mosca` element technically exists.

Fix this by putting your script at the very bottom of the `<body>`

Also, the `mosca` object will not simply exist - you do need to set it using `document.getElementById`:

```
var mosca = document.getElementById('mosca');
```

Comment: Oh, wow...makes sense. The thing is, my teacher always puts the scripts inside the head section so I came to the conclusion that scripts could not be put anywhere else, especially in the body section. Thank you !!

Comment: No problem! JavaScript executes immediately when its loaded, so more often than not, you'll actually want it to load last (ergo putting the `script` tags at the bottom of the markup). Take this new knowledge to class and call your prof out! This is a best practice that they should definitely be teaching.

Comment: Only as a side note, some browsers would work if you use `mosca` as defined, because they work with the object id as a reference to the object itself. But it's not a oficial feature, as far as I know.

Comment: @Guiri that sounds like what Desaroll mentioned. I don't really IE, but that's definitely not standard. If it works for you, go for it - but I doubt it'll work in other browsers like FF or Chrome